# Session State - multiple browsers

Tags: asp.net, session, session-state

What is the best way to keep session state between browser tabs?
I have the following scenario. I have a page where the user opens a 'project' from a grid.
I keep this project in the session as the "Current Open project".

The problem is that users can open another project from another tab in the browser. Now, they open another project and this becomes the new "Current Open project".

If they go back to the first page ... it is clearly a problem.

Is there a way to solve this situation please?

Thanks,

Joseph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you just have to handle it.

When a page tries to do something with a project, the server has to check if it's the current project that the page is trying to change or a different project, so that the server can send an error message back that the wrong project is opened.

Alternatively you can avoid keeping the current project in the session, and allow multiple projects to be opened simultaneously. As long as each page keeps track of which project it is handling (which you have to do anyway), it's not a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have not yet found a good way to have an mechanism where each page tracks its project, I just have a session variable that keeps the current open project and I set it when the project is opened. I could for example use the viewstate or the URL but this introduces problems when for example you have REST calls. Maybe I can solve this by sending the details as a header in the REST call but may complicate things more and I do not know whether it is a good approach